# Submit Form onchange and if other values 0

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I am making a small project for myself and I am having an issue in submitting the form, don't get me wrong I am able to submit it by pressing the submit button.

I have a form consisting of Text field, two drop-downs and a submit button. 
This form is working fine, but the problem is, that I want the form to also submit if the first drop down is selected, and text field is empty and the second drop down has selected its default value (not changed).

I don't want to post the whole code for obvious reasons, so if you want something specific, just ask, I will gladly post the code.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: I got a working formu but I want it to submit if the first drop down is changed but the second is left untouched and the textfield is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a javascript function, and add the onchange listerner to your select option

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/yJYjd/4/)

```
Select Box1 <select id="sel1" onchange="doCheck();" >
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
 </select>
```

Call the JS method on onChange to submit the form

```
function doCheck()
{
  var changed= false;

if(document.getElementById("text").value=="" && document.getElementById("sel1").value!="0" && document.getElementById("sel2").value=="0")
{
    changed=true;
}
    if(changed){
       alert("submitting form : "+changed);
       document.forms[0].submit;
    }
   else{
      alert("Not submit form : "+changed); 
       return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: but it doesnt submit form on first drop down menus change, or i just didnt understand how to make it work.

Comment: I haven't added the code to submit the form. See the comment //submit form here . you have to replace the alert with document.forms[0].submit.

Comment: but do I put onSubmit at the form tag? As I know the fucntion then will only be triggered if form is submited.

Comment: You want to validate the form for your submit criteria and  then submit the form. This will first validate the from and based on the return type of this function it will submit the form. If the function returns true , it will submit the form and if it returns the false it will not. This is an example I have provided for the guidance, You will have to put the logic as per your requirement.

Comment: As I understand you didnt quite well understand what I want to achieve. That is I want form to submit on changin the value of the first dropdown without pressing the submit button meanwhile the criterias are met.

Comment: Ok, then you have to add this method to onChange of select first dropdown. I will edit the fiddle.